# SQL ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column...Why it is unknown?

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

I wish to know where I did wrong in the high lighting part?
Thank you very much!

Comment: did u commit the column name?

Comment: I have figure it out.

Comment: update comp575_books, comp575_authors
 set comp575_books.publisher_id=1
 where comp575_books.author_id=comp575_authors.author_id and
 comp575_authors.first_name in ('Markus', 'Robert');

Answer (score 1):

First of all: You should not link images, but show the SQL and result as text in your request. Some people cannot open links due to browser restrictions. Also the image content cannot be searched. And if we want to try your query, we must write it instead of being able to copy and paste. At last the image link may get invalid one day. Please edit your request and show the SQL and result as text.

Anyway, as to the original error: the error mesage tells you which field is unknown. So simply look at the table and its column names, to check for typos.

As to the update query: `AND` has precedence over `OR`. So:

```
update comp575_books, comp575_authors 
set comp575_books.publisher_id=1 
where comp575_books.author_id = comp575_authors.author_id 
  and comp575_authors.first_name = 'Markus' or comp575_authors.first_name = 'Robert';
```

means

```
where (comp575_books.author_id = comp575_authors.author_id 
  and comp575_authors.first_name = 'Markus') or comp575_authors.first_name = 'Robert';
```

Use parentheses to correct this. Or use a simple *table* update statement instead of updating a view. This is more readable anyway.

```
update comp575_books
set publisher_id = 1 
where author_id in
(
  select author_id
  from comp575_authors
  where first_name in ('Markus', 'Robert')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

probably you error is when you try to compare comp575_book.author_id with comp575_author.author_id. As you can see, comp575_author isn't a valid table on your database.

Comment: update comp575_books, comp575_authors
 set comp575_books.publisher_id=1
 where comp575_books.author_id=comp575_authors.author_id and
 comp575_authors.first_name='Markus' or comp575_authors.first_name='Robert'; after

Comment: I use this command, all publisher_id turn to 1. it still not the result that I want....

Comment: Well, i don't really know which is the expected behavior, also i don't know if what i said remove the error "unknown column" error.